# sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2 not working with Sonarqube version 7.9.1

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have upgraded my Sonarqube instance (Developer Edition) from v7.3 to v7.9.1. I have upgraded jdk also from version jdk1.8.0_102 to JDK-11.0.4 as it is a prerequisite for Sonarqube v7.9.1.
Sonar maven plugin used is - `org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar`

After upgrading to Sonarqube v7.9.1, Jenkins build jobs are failing with below error -

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar (default-cli) on project myproject: Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to download libraries from server: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Now, If i upgrade sonar-maven-plugin to 3.6.1.1688, Build jobs are working fine.

Could anyone please help me to understand why it is not working with sonar-maven-plugin:3.2 ? Can I resolve it without changing the sonar-maven-plugin version?

Comment: Simple answer to that: It can't work with older versions of the plugin cause it does not support JDK11 if I correctly remember. Apart from that: What is the problem to upgrade the plugin version?

Comment: according to the plugin docs: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-maven/ you need at least the version required by the server. the last server with java 8 support is 7.8: https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.8/requirements/requirements/ - so either us that for now or upgrade the plugin - and I also don't understand why you cant upgrade the sonar maven plugin?

Comment: So we need to run two Java runtimes in order to support all components? You can set the runtime path for SonarQube.

Comment: If we upgrade the sonar-maven-plugin version then we have to make changes at project levels too as for some projects version of sonar-maven-plugin is configured in pom.xml